# Using an argument to change the config on a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a battleship game, (Yes it can be simplified a lot, i am novice to code but ahead in my high school class).

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

mainFrame = Frame(window, width=500, height=500)
mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

listShot = []

def shootAt(location):
    print(location)
    if(location in listShot):
        print()
    else:
        listShot.append(location)
        print(listShot)
        location.config(relief = SUNKEN)

A1 = Button(mainFrame, text="X", width = 4, height = 2, 
            command = lambda: shootAt(A1))
A1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
```

How would I use an argument in my buttons to change the config of the called button?

Comment: What would these configs of the called button be?

Comment: what is the problem - you already change `relief` in called button ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` to give as many arguments as you want to the `shootAt()` function

Please note: `fg` is just an example, you can change this to whatever you want

```
def shootAt(location, CONFIGURE_THIS):
    ...
    else:
        ...
        location.config(relief = SUNKEN, fg = CONFIGURE_THIS)

A1 = Button(mainFrame, text="X", width = 4, height = 2, 
            command = lambda: shootAt(A1, "orange"))
```